# ExtJs 4: How to send all modified, new and removed record in one single request?

Tags: extjs, proxy, extjs4, store, batch-processing

ExtJs data proxy sends all store modifications in separate requests.

Is there a posibility to get all operations together (create, update, destroy) in one single request? (I dont mean the batch mode, because with the batch mode there are still three operations, but I need to get it all in just one)

Records in my data bank depends on each other, so I can not delete some records from the data bank without knowing which records were added or modified.
On the server side I need all data at once, and not in 2 or 3 independend calls.

I know, I can grab all records from the store and just push them to the server, but I want to stay "extjs native"

Answer (score 1):

How about providing a transform function for the data writer in your proxy that can manipulate your data to include all the fields that you want in a format you want.

Something like

```
proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/updatemedata',
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            transform: {
                fn: function(data, request) {
                    // do some manipulation
                    return data;
                },
                scope: this
            }
        }
    }
```